# Combining Multiple columns from multiple tables into 1 unified table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, 1 with job information:

Table A:

| Job Number | Product | Quantity | Release Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job A | Prod A | 20 | 20 |
| Job B | Prod A | 50 | 10 |
| Job C | Prod B | 85 | 21 |

The other table has remake information with source information from a Job from Table A:

Table B:

| Remake Job Number | Original Job Number | Remake Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R1-Job A | Job A | 5 |
| R1-Job B | Job B | 10 |
| R1-Job C | Job C | 2 |

The output I am trying to get is a unified list of all jobs, with related information from both tables together (Product/Release Week for each remake in Table B pulled from original job in Table A).

Output Expected:

| Job Number | Product | Quantity | Release Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job A | Prod A | 20 | 20 |
| Job B | Prod A | 50 | 10 |
| Job C | Prod B | 85 | 21 |
| R1-Job A | Prod A | 5 | 20 |
| R1-Job B | Prod A | 10 | 10 |
| R1-Job C | Prod B | 2 | 21 |

I have attempted this by doing a left join with case statements as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN B.[Remake Job Number] is not null THEN B.[Remake Job Number] ELSE A.[Job Number] 
END as [Job Number], A.[Product], CASE WHEN B.[Remake Job Number] is not null THEN 
B.[Remake Quantity] ELSE A.[Quantity] END as [Quantity], A.[Release Week] from [Table A] as A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Remake Job Number], [Remake Quantity], [Original Job Number] from [Table B]) as B on A.[Job Number] = B.[Original Job Number]
```

This ends up giving me a list of all jobs without remakes and the appropriate information, and all remake jobs with correct info, but lacks the original job numbers with remakes with appropriate info.  I can see what is happening, but I'm not sure how to add those original job numbers with remakes back into the list (other than some weird IN statement).  I also tried to use COALESCE with some similar results as above.

Using SQL Server, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine results from two queries.

First, take everything just from `Table A` and then combine it with another query that joins information from `Table A` with `Table B`.

Here's how:

```
SELECT 
  A.[Job Number],
  A.[Product],
  A.[Quantity],
  A.[Release Week]
FROM
  [Table A] AS A

UNION ALL

SELECT
  B.[Remake Job Number],
  A.[Product],
  B.[Remake Quantity],
  A.[Release Week]
FROM
  [Table B] AS B
  INNER JOIN [Table A] AS A ON
    A.[Job Number] = B.[Original Job Number]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as intended!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine the result of two queries. The first one corresponds to `tablea` and the second query would require a join of both tables.

For example:

```
select * from tablea
union all
select
  b.job_number,
  a.product,
  b.remake_quantity,
  a.release_week
from tableb b
join tablea a on a.job_number = b.original_job_number
```